# Api platform add or update

Tags: api-platform.com

Good afternoon I am adding data in via POST method in PLATFORM API can I make this method work like adding or updating data.
So that when the data is already there for the object, it will simply update the pinOrder field.
My input:

```
{
  "chat": "/api/chats/01FVKRYXMMTHKJ2EZB02F4FZ3Z",
  "pinOrder": 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Insert or update*** (upsert) is not available in Api Platform. However, you can achieve this behavior with a custom (or decorated) Data Persister (called state processor as of 3.x).

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-processors/

In the persist (called process as of 3.x) method of the data persister you could manually check if an item matching your criteria does already exist and, if yes, update this one instead of persisting a new one.

Comment: Unfortunately the comment provided is a 404. Can you update, pls?

Comment: @codedge I have updated the link and naming

Answer (score 0):

You can use PRE_WRITE event. For exemple, an order item quantity.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::VIEW => [
            'updateExistingItemQuantity', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE,
        ],
    ];
}

public function updateExistingItemQuantity(
    ViewEvent $event
): void {
    $item = $event->getControllerResult();
    $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

    if (!$item instanceof MyItemObject || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
        return;
    }

    // find duplicateItem

    if ($duplicateItem) {
        $duplicateItem->setQuantity("UPDATED QUANTITY");

        // save $duplicateItem

        $event->setControllerResult($duplicateItem);
    }
}
```